# is there any way to set APN programmatically in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

We can get APN Name in Blackberry but can i know is there any way to set APN in an application. Kindly help me out on this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I didn't expect that so many people are interested

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure you can. But I think you know that apn is option for direct connection only. And I think you know that it doesn't work on many carriers. So it's preferable to use wifi, bis-b, wap2. But maybe your are targeting on specific carrier.

Preferable if target is 5.0+:

```
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
connectionFactory.setPreferedTransportTypes(new int[] {..., TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_TCP_CELLULAR,...});
TcpCellularOptions transportOptions = new TcpCellularOptions();
transportOptions.setApn("<your apn>");
transportOptions.setTunnelAuthUsername("<username if required>");
transportOptions.setTunnelAuthPassword("<password if required>");
connectionFactory.setTransportTypeOptions(TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_TCP_CELLULAR, transportOptions);
```

Rudimental if target is below 5.0 OS:

```
connection = (<corresponded connection class type>)Connector.open("<your connection prefix>" + ";deviceside=false;apn=<your apn name>;TunnelAuthUsername=<username if required>;TunnelAuthPassword=<password if required>")
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, can you please give me the complete explanation of the above code

Comment: What exactly should be explained?

Comment: why you used connection Factory?

Comment: connection = (<corresponded connection class type>)Connector.open("<your connection prefix>" + ";deviceside=false;apn=<your apn name>;TunnelAuthUsername=<username if required>;TunnelAuthPassword=<password if required>") and where to use this code?

Comment: The code with Connector class should be used if your target OS is below 5.0 - 4.5, 4.6, 4.7. If you'll try ConnectionFactory in 4.6 you won't be able to run application because ConnectionFactory API was introduced in 5.0 by RIM